# Sending JSON from Python server

Tags: python, c#, json, sockets

Using PyZMQ to set up a client Socket connection in Unity.
The server is responding with a JSON Object which is converted to a String before sending using the Python json.dumps() method

My question is should the JSON Object be converted to a String BEFORE sending it to the client or left as a JSON Object?

Right now I am receiving

```
"{\"timestamp\": 1233456,\"foo\": 2,\"nofoo\": 0,\"foo_count\": 234,\"nofoo_count\": 12}"
```

which makes it difficult to parse.

Comment: It seems like you've answered your own question - if you convert to string *then* to JSON, that's what you get.

Comment: A JSON *is* a string. You may also say a "JSON string". That is what you get from `json.dumps()`. When you receive it, you have to convert it to the original object using `json.loads()`

Comment: Why is JSON difficult to parse?  You should be able to use JSON Deserialize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have C# tagged, so parsing this message in C# (dotnet core 3.1) should just be

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

var data = "{\"timestamp\": 1233456,\"foo\": 2,\"nofoo\": 0,\"foo_count\": 234,\"nofoo_count\": 12}";

var jsonData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyData>(data);
```

Where your POCO just looks like:

```
class MyData
{
  public int timestamp { get; set; }
  public int foo { get; set; }
  public int nofoo { get; set; }
  public int foo_count { get; set; }
  public int nofoo_count { get; set; }
}
```